# How will the selected layered navigation apply to all categories?

Tags: layered-navigation, navigation

I have a set of attributes which can be filtered with layered navigation. But when I set the filter in one category it should stay when I list the products in another category. But unfortunately I have to set the filter again when changing to another category. How can I solve this? Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Which problems did you encounter? Save the filter to session and reuse them on request.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can save layered navigation selection in the session. For this you may use of the pre-dispatch events.

And update the `Mage::app()->getRequest()->setParam('color', 13);` Where 13 is the value you have saved on the previous step from the request.

You also need to handle the params clearing  and changing, so the values from the request have higher priority thet the same saved params in the session.